# App won't run on device

Tags: xcode7.3

This is how XCode looks when the app first runs on the phone...

[image]

Here's the project navigator. I added all the frameworks because another answer suggested it, but it didn't need them before.

[image]

Here is the device log...

> Jun  3 22:16:57 Ians-iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbukD.png)
>   (UIKitApplication:com.MyApp.MyApp.UI[0x8927][902]) : Service
>   exited due to signal: Killed: 9 Jun  3 22:16:57 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [901] : Got a 'k' packet,
>   killing the inferior process. Jun  3 22:16:57 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [901] : Sending ptrace PT_KILL
>   to terminate inferior process. Jun  3 22:16:57 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [901] : 1 +0.000000 sec
>   [0385/0c07]: error: ::ptrace (request = PT_THUPDATE, pid = 0x0386, tid
>   = 0x2b07, signal = 0) err = Resource busy (0x00000010) Jun  3 22:16:57 Ians-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [901] : Waited 10 ms for
>   process to be reaped (state = Exited) Jun  3 22:16:57 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [901] : 2 +0.013070 sec
>   [0385/1107]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x16e2d2a38, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad
>   file descriptor (0x00000009) Jun  3 22:16:57 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [901] : Exiting. Jun  3
>   22:16:57 Ians-iPhone SpringBoard[58] : Application
>   'UIKitApplication:com.MyApp.MyApp.UI[0x8927]' exited abnormally via
>   signal. Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] :
>   0x16e1bb000 -[MIClientConnection
>   _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/UI.app_sparse.ipa" type Developer
>   (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by streaming_zip_conduit (pid 792)
>   Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 0x16e1bb000
>   -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing  Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] :
>   0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstallableBundlePatch applyPatchWithError:]:
>   Attempting patch update of com.MyApp.MyApp.UI from 1 (1.0) to 1 (1.0)
>   Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone profiled[157] : (Note ) MC:
>   Provisioning profiles changed Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone
>   profiled[157] : (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust... Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:16 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 0x16e1bb000
>   -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.MyApp.MyApp.UI is now at
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/89118C1E-9A27-4EA0-B26D-8698EEF941D5
>   Jun  3 22:17:17 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 0x16e1bb000
>   -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.MyApp.MyApp.UI at
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FD7042F3-8D64-454F-A646-A7C3553E7B4A
>   Jun  3 22:17:17 Ians-iPhone installd[753] : 0x16e1bb000
>   -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.27s, Verifying:
>   0.11s; Overall: 1.11s Jun  3 22:17:17 Ians-iPhone pkd[111] : releasing plug-in hold 18687614-D5AE-4471-998C-6C6D4B0E00A1 at
>   client's request Jun  3 22:17:17 Ians-iPhone online-auth-agent[170]
>   :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>   Jun  3 22:17:17 Ians-iPhone syncdefaultsd[908] : (Note )
>   marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "opportunistic" on
>    Jun  3 22:17:17 Ians-iPhone
>   syncdefaultsd[908] : (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice"
>   topic as "enabled" on  Jun  3 22:17:17
>   Ians-iPhone SpringBoard[58] : Installed apps did change.
>     Added: {(   )}  Removed: {(     )}  Modified: {(
>         "com.MyApp.MyApp.UI"    )} Jun  3 22:17:18 Ians-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [909] :
>   debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
>   for arm64. Jun  3 22:17:18 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [909] : Connecting to
>   com.apple.debugserver service... Jun  3 22:17:18 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [909] : Got a connection,
>   waiting for process information for launching or attaching. Jun  3
>   22:17:19 Ians-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [909] : Sending AppProxy info:
>   sequence no: 202, GUID: B89B714A-35DE-43E5-9655-D4EDC8D8ED76. Jun  3
>   22:17:19 Ians-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [909] : error: Unrecognized
>   event type: .  Ignoring. Jun  3 22:17:19 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [909] : About to launch
>   process for bundle ID: com.MyApp.MyApp.UI Jun  3 22:17:19 Ians-iPhone
>   SpringBoard[58] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName
>   SubjectCommonName] Jun  3 22:17:19 Ians-iPhone SpringBoard[58]
>   :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>   Jun  3 22:17:19 Ians-iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbukD.png)
>   (UIKitApplication:com.MyApp.MyApp.UI[0xb236]) : The DisableASLR
>   key is no longer respected. Please remove it. Jun  3 22:17:19
>   Ians-iPhone securityd[92] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements
>   MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:19
>   Ians-iPhone securityd[92] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements
>   MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:19
>   Ians-iPhone amfid[250] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf
>   IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3 22:17:19 Ians-iPhone
>   kernel[0] : xpcproxy[910] Container:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/89118C1E-9A27-4EA0-B26D-8698EEF941D5
>   (sandbox) Jun  3 22:17:19 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [909] : In completion handler,
>   got pid for bundle id, pid: 910. Jun  3 22:17:19 Ians-iPhone
>   com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver 
>   PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124     [909] : Got a connection,
>   launched process
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FD7042F3-8D64-454F-A646-A7C3553E7B4A/UI.app
>   (pid = 910). Jun  3 22:17:19 Ians-iPhone SpringBoard[58] :
>   LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image Jun  3 22:17:21
>   Ians-iPhone securityd[92] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements
>   MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21
>   Ians-iPhone securityd[92] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements
>   MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21
>   Ians-iPhone amfid[250] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf
>   IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone
>   securityd[92] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain
>   entitlements: no stored taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone
>   securityd[92] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain
>   entitlements: no stored taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone
>   amfid[250] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName
>   SubjectCommonName] Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  3
>   22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone securityd[92] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Jun  3 22:17:21 Ians-iPhone amfid[250] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your project navigator at this same instant?

Comment: Any relevant messages in the device log?

Comment: @PhillipMills I've added the device log to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I synced the device to my computer and examined the crash report. It said...

> Dyld Error Message: Dyld Message: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC13701-64BE-4DED-9DEB-5346E0A18EE3/UI.app/Frameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
>   Reason: image not found   Dyld Version: 390.7

So, I'd not added one of the libraries.